# My administrator password doesn't work

Tags: password, administrator

I have recently loaded Ubuntu from a CD. My administrator password doesn't work when logging into Ubuntu at the opening screen.

Comment: Normally, you would not have (or need) an administrator password.  The proper way to perform administrative tasks is by using "sudo" or ("gksudo" for graphical apps).

Comment: Are you able to log in at all? Or are you only able to use the "guest" account?

Answer (score 1):

Boot while holding the shift key down. You'll then be greeted by a GRUB menu. You want to select boot recovery mode. Once in recovery mode you can passwd yourusername to set a new password.

Comment: same problem!  L am getting "authentication token manipulation" messages.  Don't know what this means.